# ContentEditable caret incorrect values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the position in pixels of caret in a contenteditable div, for that I'm using:

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
```

Everything works fine except when the caret is before first character of each line (except first line), the result is the same as if caret was after last character of previous line. With break lines there is no problem, the problem occours in a node with multiple lines.
Example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Darm0ka/qw1v82qz/1/

Comment: you have nothing in fiddle

Comment: Sorry, https://jsfiddle.net/Darm0ka/qw1v82qz/1/

Comment: I didn't understand please explain in brief

Comment: For example if I click in second line the result is 18 (in chrome) but if I click in second line before first character at beginning the result is 0 and I expect 18. How can I get 18 with that click?